# MySQL Workbench not respect when selecting a certain table

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am using MySQL Workbench CE 6.2 and every time I try to access information from a certain table, it takes FOREVER to do anything. Its connected to the server and everything, and properly displays the information from other tables. For example:

```
    select *
    from concepts;
```

This code works fine, but if I try to do the same with one specific table, MySQL will take forever and eventually read as "Not Responding". Is there anything I can do to correct this or do I just have to wait it out? Help me please

Comment: What does `select count(*) from concepts;` say?

Comment: 2450. The table itself that causes MySQL to crash is called 'obs'

Comment: Ok, so what is the row count on that `obs` table? If it is a huge number, that might explain why it takes so long. I believe the workbench also has a built-in feature to browse tables, which limits the number of visible results to something manageable.

Comment: the count for that is 476973. so i went limit 1000, thank you very much that worked perfectly.

Comment: Try the current WB version, which today is 6.3.5.